# UIPickerView delegate not called in a subview

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipickerview

I have a simple iOS app that uses UISegmentedControl to switch between two tabs.

In ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var segment: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewContainer: UIView!
    var searchView: UIView!
    var favView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchView = SearchViewController().view
    favView = FavoriteViewController().view
    viewContainer.addSubview(favView)
    viewContainer.addSubview(searchView)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func segmentChange(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex{
    case 0:
        viewContainer.bringSubview(toFront: searchView)
        break
    case 1:
        viewContainer.bringSubview(toFront: favView)
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
}
```

And in the first tab, I have a UIPickerView as input of a Textfield.

```
import UIKit

class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var keywordField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var categoryField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var distanceField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationField: UITextField!

    var cgpicker = UIPickerView()
    let categories = ["Default", "Airport", "Amusement Park", "Aquarium", "Art Gallery", "Bakery", "Bar"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    cgpicker.delegate = self
    cgpicker.dataSource = self
    categoryField.inputView = cgpicker
    categoryField.text = categories[0]
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    print("picker working")
    return categories.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return categories[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    categoryField.text = categories[row]
    categoryField.resignFirstResponder()
}

}
```

However, when I click the Textfield, the PickerView doesn't display data. In fact the delegate and datasource is not called since the "print" is never called. However the same code is working fine in a simple UIView app. I cannot find any solution related to this problem.

[UIPickerView not showing data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1yTO.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `viewDidLoad` of your `ViewController` class.

You are not creating the container view controller properly. The primary issue preventing the picker from working is that your `SearchViewController` has no strong reference to it when `viewDidLoad` finishes so the picker in `SearchViewController` becomes `nil`.

Update the `ViewController viewDidLoad` to something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let searchVC = SearchViewController()
    searchView = searchVC.view
    addChildViewController(searchVC)
    // Should set searchView frame or constraints
    viewContainer.addSubview(searchView)
    searchVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    let favVC = FavoriteViewController()
    favView = favVC.view
    addChildViewController(favVC)
    // Should set favView frame or constraints
    viewContainer.addSubview(favView)
    favVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

Comment: You are a life saver.

Comment: @adecentalien Glad to help. Please don't forget to indicate your question has been solved by accepting the answer that best resolved your issue.

Comment: @rmaddy Can this also be accomplished dynamically (number of sub views not known beforehand, meaning I can't declare variables like `searchView` before)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65882928/keeping-strong-references-with-dynamic-subviews-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

This because you not load picker

you should have reference to `SearchViewController` not reference to its View

**ViewController:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var segment: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewContainer: UIView!
    var searchController: SearchViewController!
    var favController: FavoriteViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchController = SearchViewController()
        favController = FavoriteViewController()
        viewContainer.addSubview(searchController.view)
        viewContainer.addSubview(favController.view)
        searchController.loadPickerView()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


    @IBAction func segmentChange(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex{
        case 0:
            viewContainer.bringSubview(toFront: searchController.view)
             searchController.loadPickerView()
            break
        case 1:
            viewContainer.bringSubview(toFront: favController.view)
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Add loadPickerView `func` to  `SearchViewController`

```
 func loadPickerView() {
        cgpicker.delegate = self
        cgpicker.dataSource = self
        self.textFieldUserName.inputView = cgpicker
        textFieldUserName.text = categories[0]
    }
```

Comment: There's no need for the `loadPickerView` method. The picker view is already being setup in the `viewDidLoad` of `SearchViewController`.

Comment: And there's a lot more to creating a container view controller than just adding subviews.

Comment: ok, we highlighted the problem why picker not loaded. he can do best practices solution according to this