# Keeping strong references with dynamic subviews in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to implement a dynamic view composed UI elements sent by the backend, meaning it is not known beforehand how many and which UI elements will be displayed, the server sends JSON containing the types of fields that need to be rendered.

So for example the sever sends:

- type: paragraph
- type: textfield

Then I instantiate a class I have for each of those elements and **add their views as subviews** to my main dynamic view:

```swift
class DynamicViewController: UIViewController {
    // array of subviews, textfield is one element in this array (-> textfield not editable)
    var subViews: [UIView] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        getFields(completion: { result in
            for (index, element) in result!.form.enumerated() {
                let initializedClass = element.getClass()
                self.subViews.append(initializedClass.view)
                self.addChild(initializedClass)
                self.view.addSubview(self.subViews[index])
                initializedClass.didMove(toParent: self)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**The problem** I am getting with the "textfield" element, is that the textfield doesn't seem to be editable, tapping on it does nothing.
However, when I change the code to assign the `initializedClass.view` to a specific variable, it does work:

```swift
class DynamicViewController: UIViewController {
    // variable specifically for the textfield's view (-> textfield is editable)
    var textfieldView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        getFields(completion: { result in
            for (index, element) in result!.form.enumerated() {
                if (index == 0) {
                    let initializedClass = element.getClass()
                    let initializedView = initializedClass.view
                    self.textfieldView = initializedClass.view
                    self.addChild(initializedClass)
                    self.view.addSubview(initializedView!)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

This second implementation works then (the picker does open), which I got from [UIPickerView delegate not called in a subview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50661575/uipickerview-delegate-not-called-in-a-subview).

**My question** is why this is happening and how I can make this work without having to declare static variables for each element, but rather work with an array or some collection that keep references to the elements.

The TextField:

```swift
class CustomTextField: UIViewController {
    private let labelElement = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 150, width: 350, height: 20))
    private let textfieldElement = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 200, width: 350, height: 40))
    
    init(label: String) {
        self.labelElement.text = label
        textfieldElement.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.roundedRect
        
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(labelElement)
        view.addSubview(textfieldElement)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code it looks like `getClass()` will return a subclass of `UIViewController` (I can see this because you are calling `addChild`). You also have to call `initializedClass.didMove(toParent: self)` sometimes after `addChild` otherwise the embedding of the VC is not completed and could cause issues. I am not entirely sure this is the cause of your problem but I suggest to try it. Also when implementing a container VC you need to take care of AutoLayout for the children's view, where are you managing the constraints? If you don't add any constraint the view of the VC you are adding as child will have the same size of the main `UIWindow`.
You actually could also get rid of `var subViews: [UIView] = []` and just rely on `children` array from `UIViewController`. It will contain all the VCs you add when calling `addChild`.

Comment: I already tried `didMove`, see my updated question. Sadly no change. I'm not doing anything about the layout right now, true, this will come next. I thought it's necessary to keep a reference to the views, the delegates don't seem to be called.

Comment: So at the moment your only issue is about delegate not getting called? Can you show us the code related to that?

Comment: Well at least I think so: The textfield gets rendered but I tap on it and nothing happens (first code in my question). With the second code example, the keyboard opens and it is editable. Added the TextField code

Comment: Okay, I think you are right about the layouts. This seems to be a layout issue. I can see the elements but they are overlapping each other, thereby not being clickable.